# Using VBA to output a value in a column given a certain input column of variable length in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like VBA to read that column, and then output values into a new column based on conditions:- I want to find the values which define the top 33% of the values and the bottom 33% values in the column being read. For example, if the value in column A is between 1,2,3,4,5,6 my answers are 2 and 5 to be shown in columns B and C. I want to use this for input columns of variable length.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The question isn't very clear, I'm afraid. Seeing your existing code -- and possibly an image of the result you want -- would definitely help.

Comment: `find the values which define the top 33% of the values and the bottom 33% values ` How did you arrive at 2 and 5? Shouldn't it be 1,2 for bottom And 5,6 for top 33%?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using VBA to output a value in a column given a certain input column of variable length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963769/using-vba-to-output-a-value-in-a-column-given-a-certain-input-column-of-variable)

Comment: By defining the top 33% I mean the value x such that top 33% values are >= x. so I want x, y such that top 33% values>=x and bottom 33%<=y. so the code takes an array of column values as input and then sorts and finds the values x, y. I want to know how to read a variable length column from worksheet and then write the output values to the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be:

1. Pull the values in an integer array
2. Sort the array using some sorting algorithm(in case the values are not in ascending/descending order)
3. Remove duplicates if any.
4. Get the values by using a simple formula involving array length.
5. Put the values in required cells.